# How to get the Ads that are relevant to the user's app usage in android

Tags: android

Can I know whether there is a way to refine the Ads according to the users needs or user browsing content and show only those Ads in my app in android.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding the ads in the mobile then its totally depends on the ads provider. If you are adding the `admob` full screen ads then they provide to option his console for image and video ads only. It depends on the ads provider. You can not refine the `ads` as per your requirements.
The library of ads provide will automatically grab the data from the phone and display the ads according to it.

Comment: Can I know if there is a provider who can provide the developers to filter the ad's that he can get on his app??

Comment: You can check in the developer console of the ads provider.